# Google Sheets - Count of compared rows based on another cell

Tags: google-sheets

How would I build a formula in Google Sheets that counts the number of rows assigned to a particular manager where the value in column C does not match the corresponding row in column D.  Basically I need to compare the calculated hours to the approved hours in each row for the employees and count the number of rows where the Approved hours for the employee do not match the Calculated Hours

Example:

```
Employee         Manager        CHours         AHours
Alex             Brian          8              8
Brad             Markus         14             8
Frank            Markus         8              0
John             Brian          8.5            8
Tom              Kenneth        8              6
Zlatan           Kenneth        5.5            0
```

The result should be:

```
Manager          Count of Unapproved Hours
Brian            1
Markus           2
Kenneth          2
```

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({B2:B, IF(C2:C>D2:D, C2:C-D2:D, )}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col2)
  where Col1 is not null
  group by Col1
  label Col1'Manager',count(Col2)'Count of Unapproved Hours'"))
```

[image]

Comment: We have over 200 employees, how do i get the results to another tab

Comment: @BrianGall see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mzmPSrwF2R1YcnhudrWtp7TbtLgvcGmr9v4_FWu25Gs/edit#gid=880095113

Answer (score 0):

[Link to Example Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f4rBPbOW96DIElSx9avFM4yYZ9t2K5a7x_8D0aiuoUg/edit?usp=sharing)

I made a sheet to show how I would solve it.  I would add a column to see if the calculated hours are less than or equal to the approved hours and return a result.  I would then use =countifs() to check to see each name and if there were any results that were not approved.

formula for approved/not approved

```
=if(C3<=D3,"approved","not approved")
```

formula for counting not approved:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$8,B12,$E$3:$E$8,"not approved")
```

Comment: This is similar to what i already have, I am just unable to have it pull the "Fail" reference from another tab.    =COUNTIFS('Workday Data '!$E$1:$E$392,$A$6,'Workday Data '!$T$2:$T$392,"Fail")

Comment: I feel like your formula should drop the $ from A6?
`=COUNTIFS('Workday Data '!$E$1:$E$392,A6,'Workday Data '!$T$2:$T$392,"Fail")`

Comment: Or does your Workday Data tab have a space at the end of it?  'Workday Data '! vs 'Workday Data'!   ?

Comment: My formula works fine when I am looking at another column of 0 hours or less.   =COUNTIFS('Workday Data '!$E$1:$E$392,$A$6,'Workday Data '!$K$1:$K$392, "<0")  But the current formula doesn't help when the manager has partially approved some hours.